# mustache.js is stuck on 0.4.0-dev in my rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, mustache

Has anyone ever experienced this? I have vendor'd mustache.js 0.5.1. My vendor'd file is what is served by Rails and what I see in the browser. It's functions are not executed when I call Mustache.to_html (0.4.0 does not have `Mustache.render`, which is how I discovered this problem). A call to `Mustache.version` returns '0.4.0-dev'. Something, somewhere, is doing something evil.

- vendor/assets/javascripts/mustache.js is 0.5.1.
- `Mustache.version` in the Chrome console returns '0.4.0-dev'... so something is overwriting the Mustache prototype. Something evil.
- we've killed code/rubymonk/tmp
- we've bounced the asset cache
- we've set assets to debug mode
- we've switched to production, precompiled the assets, and looked for lingering junk
- we do not seem to have a 0.4.0 version of mustache loaded in the browser -- but our 0.5.1 code doesn't execute (console.log statements we've added don't run, the actual mustache file is never hit by the debugger)
- we've done a full grep of the code/rubymonk directory for 'mustache' and '0.4.0-dev'.... nadda (other than what you'd expect)
- we've looked over the whole hard drive (at least as well as Spotlight does... but it seems to do a pretty good job)
- we've grepped the gems directory for both 'mustache' and '0.4.0-dev'... again, nothing.

If I'm actually doing something wrong, I'll post the solution once we sort it.

-s-

Answer (score 1):

Resolved! Our app is using Intercom (http://intercom.io) -- which is otherwise brilliant -- but it appears the intercom Javascript we download is blowing away `Mustache` in the global namespace.

I'll send them a message asking them to namespace their stuff. In the meantime I guess we'll just have to tinker with our own copy of mustache.js to namespace it differently. Which is to say, add the following:

```
var MyApp = MyApp || {};
```

And replace occurances of `Mustache` with `MyApp.Mustache`.

Hopefully this helps someone else. If not, at least I can enjoy sailing ephemeral boats onto the StackOverflow sea.

-steven

PS: We found this out because we were trying to render mustache partials on the client side in pure Javascript, which was apparently broken in mustache 0.4.0 (it would simply spit out our `{{ > mypartial }}` call directly into the HTML, rendering nothing.